# What is the delay for DFSR before it begins sending a file or files?

Tags: windows-server-2003, dfs, dfs-r

I have heard rumor there could be an hour delay between when I could drop a file in the source folder and when it actually begins transmission to the destination. However, I can't find this in any documentation from Microsoft.

I imagined it would just watch the files in my source folder for changes and begin transfer immediately, but from what I've heard it seems like it will be 'polling' for changes every hour.

Can anyone confirm or disprove this? If it's true, is the frequency configurable to more often than every hour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so i hope this is a better answer then the previous.

Usually data is replicated within seconds after a file change and you can define time windows during wich the data can be replicated (you can also use bandwidth throttling), by default DFS-R use the RDC protocol (Remote differential compression) to transfer only the compressed binary diff of the files changed to minimize bandwith requirements.

Hope this helps.

There is more informations in this [MS Technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772778(WS.10).aspx).